# Infinite Scroll using Algolia on React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, algolia, react-functional-component, intersection-observer

I'm trying to implement infinite scrolling on my react app for search hits from Algolia.

I came across a class component in their documentation. And I use React Hooks so tried to make it work on React Hooks. All I got was so many renders and my app gets hung up when this component mounts.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActionArea from '@material-ui/core/CardActionArea';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { connectHits, connectInfiniteHits } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';
import noItemImage from './../../assets/img/noItemImage.png'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import ShareIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Share';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function AlgoliaHits(props) {
    const { hits } = props
    console.log(hits)
    var sentinel = useRef(null)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        function onSentinelIntersection (entries){
            const { hasMore, refine } = props

            entries.forEach(entry => {
                if (entry.isIntersecting && hasMore) {
                    refine()
                }
            })
        }

        var observer = new IntersectionObserver(onSentinelIntersection, {})

        observer.observe(sentinel.current)
        return () => {
            observer.disconnect()
        }
    }, [props])

    return (
        <Container maxWidth="md" style={{ marginBottom: 100 }}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                {
                    hits.map(hit => (
                        <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={4} xl={3}>
                            <Link to={`/item/${hit.item_id}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                                <Card maxWidth={210} key={hit.item_id} elevation={0}>
                                    <CardActionArea>
                                        <CardMedia
                                            component="img"
                                            alt="Contemplative Reptile"
                                            height="140"
                                            image={
                                                hit.item_images_url ? 
                                                    hit.item_images_url.length === 0 ?
                                                    noItemImage
                                                    :
                                                    hit.item_images_url[0]
                                                : 
                                                noItemImage
                                            }
                                            title={hit.item_name}
                                        />
                                        <CardContent>
                                            <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2"
                                                style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap', width: 250, overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis' }}>
                                                {hit.item_name}
                                            </Typography>
                                            <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p" 
                                                style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap', width: 200, overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis'  }}>
                                                {hit.item_description}
                                    </Typography>
                                        </CardContent>
                                    </CardActionArea>
                                    <CardActions>
                                        <Button size="small" color="primary" component={Link} to={`/item/${hit.item_id}`}>
                                            View
                                        </Button>
                                        <IconButton size="small" color="secondary">
                                            <ShareIcon style={{ padding: 4 }}/>
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </CardActions>
                                </Card>
                            </Link>
                        </Grid>                        
                    ))
                }
            </Grid>
            <div id="sentinel" ref={sentinel} />
        </Container>
    );
}

AlgoliaHits.propTypes = {
    hits: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
    hasMore: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    refine: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

const AlgoliaInfiniteScroll = connectHits(AlgoliaHits)

const ItemCard = connectInfiniteHits(AlgoliaInfiniteScroll)

export default ItemCard
```

And [here's](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/ui-and-ux-patterns/infinite-scroll/react/) where I used the reference from. What wrong am I doing? And how to solve it?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

My first thought here is that the issue may be in the `useEffect` dependency array.

The `useEffect` hook will trigger whenever one of it's dependencies changes. In your case, you've specified the dependency array as `[props]`, meaning every time a prop changes, it will trigger once more. As `props` likely changes quite often, for objects such as `props.hits`, I'd wager this is throwing your code into the infinite loops you mention.

I believe in the original example, the `onSentinelIntersection` functionality only occurs once, when the component mounts.

I'd start with an empty dependency array: `[]` at the end of your useEffect. This is a (albeit a little bit hacky) way to replace `componentDidMount` and only run once, when the component's first render.

If that helps, you may be most of the way there. I would also recommend, however, moving the `onSentinelIntersection` function out of the `useEffect` (or even completely out of the component, if possible!) - as it's good practice to keep as much code outside of a useEffect as possible (as it'll be evaluated every time it executes).

So something like:

```
function AlgoliaHits(props) {
    const { hits } = props
    console.log(hits)
    var sentinel = useRef(null)
    
    function onSentinelIntersection (entries){
        const { hasMore, refine } = props

        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting && hasMore) {
                refine()
            }
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        var observer = new IntersectionObserver(onSentinelIntersection, {})
        observer.observe(sentinel.current)

        return () => observer.disconnect()
    }, [])

    ....
```

May be a good start. You may be able to safely add `[IntersectionObserver, onSentinelIntersection]` to the `useEffect` dependencies too, as they're technically required for the useEffect to function, and shouldn't cause any further triggers of `useEffect` in this case.

The [Dependencies & Performance](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) section of the [React useEffect docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is helpful here- as well as the whole page itself.

For extra resources, I really got a lot of mileage out of [The Complete Guide To useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abramov - Long read, but worth it, I think (when you have the time, that is!)